# Can two SyncLocked code blocks, which are Locked with a same object, ever execute at the same time?

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization

I just want to make sure I understand SyncLock correctly. Given the following code is it safe to say that none of these blocks will ever be executed at the same time? Or is it safe to say that no other code will be executed during the execution of any of those blocks? I am having trouble understanding what exactly a SyncLock does and why it needs a random object to lock on?

```
Dim PADLOCK As Object = New Object()
```

Block A:

```
SyncLock PADLOCK
   '...Code
End SyncLock
```

Block B:

```
SyncLock PADLOCK
   '...Code
End SyncLock
```

Block C:

```
SyncLock PADLOCK
   '...Code
End SyncLock
```

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking (examples written in C#, but the `lock` keyword is the same as `SyncLock` in Visual Basic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely.

Firstly, locks are re-entrant, so if one method calls into another (or into the same method recursively), you could have both in use **by the same thread**.

Secondly, if "...Code" contains a `Monitor.Wait` - that *relinquishes* the lock; in which case you could have two threads in the methods, but **only one of the threads active**. The `Wait` call blocks until the waiting thread can re-obtain the lock - so it remains the case that at most one thread "has" the lock.

Comment: So say Block A contained some code that iterated through some list and was running in ThreadA. Then say ThreadB calls BlockB which tries to add and object to the list what happens? Does ThreadB wait for ThreadA to unlock or not?

Comment: @vanattab yes - as long as A doesn't call Monitor.Wait, then ThreaadB is blocked until ThreadA reaches the end of the SyncLock

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The code **within** the same block will not be executed at the same time by different threads. When the process reaches end of SyncLock, CLR releases the lock.

Why you need a "random" object (as you said) requires a lot more explanation and a bit more deep understanding of how are the CLR objects constructed, laid-out in memory and managed.

If shortly, you always should use a Reference type in lock statements and this object must be non-public to prevent the dead-locks. Again, it's really hard to explain all that in the short answer and I would recommend Jeffrey Richter's book "CLR via .Net" - he goes very deep on this and other .Net fundamental topics.